# How to read values from this XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services, soap

I'm trying to read the xml from a soap response. It is given below

```
`<OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.9.2" PricedItinCount="1" BrandedOneWayItinCount="0" SimpleOneWayItinCount="0" DepartedItinCount="0" SoldOutItinCount="0" AvailableItinCount="0">
    <Success xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05"/>
    <Warnings xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">...</Warnings>
    <PricedItineraries xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
        <PricedItinerary SequenceNumber="1">
                <AirItinerary DirectionInd="OneWay">
                        <OriginDestinationOptions>
                                <OriginDestinationOption ElapsedTime="1920">
                                        <FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2017-03-21T21:45:00" ArrivalDateTime="2017-03-22T09:50:00" StopQuantity="0" FlightNumber="7336" ResBookDesigCode="T" ElapsedTime="425">
                                                <DepartureAirport LocationCode="CDL" TerminalID="1"/>
                                                <ArrivalAirport LocationCode="CDA" TerminalID="1A"/>
                                                <OperatingAirline Code="AA" FlightNumber="810"/>
                                                <Equipment AirEquipType="000"/>
                                                <MarketingAirline Code="PP"/>
                                                <DisclosureAirline Code="AC"/>
                                                <MarriageGrp>O</MarriageGrp>
                                                <DepartureTimeZone GMTOffset="-10"/>
                                                <ArrivalTimeZone GMTOffset="11"/>
                                                <TPA_Extensions>
                                                        <eTicket Ind="true"/>
                                                </TPA_Extensions>
                                        </FlightSegment>
                                </OriginDestinationOption>
                        </OriginDestinationOptions>
                </AirItinerary>
        </PricedItinerary>
</PricedItineraries>
</OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS>`
```

I've tried a lot of stuff with LINQ to XML, but nothing seems to work.

Here's a sample i've tried using

```
var xml = XDocument.Parse(stringXMLResponse);
        var result = from item in xml.Descendants("FlightSegment")
                 select new
                 {
                     v1 = item.FirstAttribute.Value
                 };
```

Any suggestions would be encouraged. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your LINQ query like this. You may need to tweak it your requirement but it works with your XML string.

```
var selected = from x in xdoc.Descendants()
              where x.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element 
              && x.Name.LocalName == "FlightSegment"
              select x;
```

Here is fiddler : https://dotnetfiddle.net/NxkT38